# Proving $n!=n(n-1)!$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

Recently, I saw a question like this. But I knew that It's just a concept that $$n!=n(n-1)(n-2)......(3)(2)(1)$$
But the question had made me curious if there is any proof of the statement.

> Show that, $$n!=n(n-1)!$$

So after seeing the question my attempt was :
$$6!=6.5.4.3.2.1=6(6-1)(6-2)(6-3)(6-4)(6-5)=6(6-1)!$$
Taking n=6 hence proved.
But I believe there is some other way to prove it, what's that?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/290964/1008071) not duplicate

Comment: A proof by induction is what you are looking for

Comment: This question is not clear.  What you are asked to show is to many the **definition** of factorial.  How, if not by way of $n!=n(n-1)!$ with $0!=1$ do you *define* the factorial function?

Comment: If perhaps you choose to define the factorial function combinatorially... by way of $n!$ is defined to be the number of distinct arrangements of $n$ distinct objects in a line, note that to "arrange all $n$ objects" you may "first choose where the $n$'th object goes then choose where the remaining $n-1$ objects go."

Comment: Just a tip.you  cannot prove something by taking examples.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the mathematical induction.

Claim) $n!=n(n-1)!$.

if $n=1$:

$1!=1 \cdot (1-1)! = 1 \cdot 0! = 1 \cdot 1 = 1.$

Let's assume that the claim is right until $n=k$.

if $n=k+1$:

$(k+1)! = (k+1)(k)(k-1)(k-2)\cdots (2)(1) = (k+1)\{(k)(k-1)(k-2)\cdots(2)(1)\} = (k+1) \cdot k!$

$\therefore n! = n(n-1)!$.

Comment: What is your $P(n)$, your definition of factorial? This is a cyclical argument.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake, the concept of the factorial is $n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(2)(1) = \displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n} i$, just like the writer wrote. So, I just proved the statement with this concept.

Comment: Check JMoravitz's comment above. This is not a proof. Again, how do you define the factorial?